# TypeScript Type of generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I can't get my head arround the following paragraph in the TypeScript documentation:

"The type of generic functions is just like those of non-generic functions, with the type parameters listed first, similarly to function declarations:"

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let myIdentity: <T>(arg: T) => T = identity;
```

What does the last line do and why is it used?

As far as I understood, myIdentity is a variable which gets the type of the identity function? And if this is the case why do I need to define such a variable? The function identity already declares what return type I can expect.

Comment: As for the question "why do I need to define such a variable," the answer is that in this case you don't. It's just there as an example of another syntax for declaring a function with that type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last line declares a variable named `myIdentity`. The variable is of a function type, a generic function (the `<T>` makes the it the signature of a generic function, more type arguments could be in the list) which takes an argument of type `T` and returns a value of type`T`. And then initializes the variable with the `identity` function which conforms to the declared signature of myIdentity.

You may want to do this in order to assign different functions to `myIdentity` based on runtime conditions. Or declare a parameter of this type and pass it to a function that can invoke it later.

Answer (score 14):

Lets say that from the compiler perspective explicit type declaration is not necessary
because of type inference.

```
let myIdentity: <T>(arg: T) => T = identity;
```

is equivalent to

```
let myIdentity = identity
```

Nevertheless, from the human side, it can be used for improving code readability.

Comment: so if I want to define a type `type Identity<T> = <T>(arg: T) => T` and then define `let myIdentity: Identity<T> = (e: T) => e`, is that illegal?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. It is legal to declare a generic type alias like `type Identity<T> = (arg: T) => T`
and then use it like `let myIdentity:  Identity<String> = (arg: String) => arg`.
`Identity<T>` is a generic type alias, you have to define a specific type when declaring a variable of type `Identity<T>`, in this case `String`.