# Define generic function type and apply to function assignment

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I can define and use a generic function like this:

```
const fetchData = <T>(): T[] => {
  const arr: T[] = []
  // if stuff push to arr
  return arr
}

const emptyStringArray = fetchData<string>();
```

However, in my actual scenario, I have a lot of params and would like to separate out the typings and function assignment.

I've attempted to write like this:

```
type IFetchData = <T>() => T[]

const fetchData2: IFetchData = () => {
  const arr: T[] = []
  // if stuff push to arr
  return arr
}

const emptyStringArray = fetchData2<string>();
```

However, now the function definition doesn't recognize the `T` as an available type.

> Cannot find name 'T'.

I've tried a lot of different configurations on where to put the `<T>`, but nothing seems to work - any ideas?

#### [Demo in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgGYFM5gBYBECGccIC8CAPACoB8AFAJQBcCZA2gLpEUIDeoCCksiHACchDZm2KseCAPQyEASyQJ4AVyTKADqpgYEcCAmFDpQtKqFQjI0AF9Q-eAhQBbTXACeAZThCFUAHMAQREcDwBGImQ0TFx8Eng-QOoaAG5QDJBPTRQEAEkAMRjsPAJichT2RilwaCdUdBL8ACYGQuK4soRaKu4QXkdBETFWKJreOUVlNQ0EbV19Q2NTc0trExB7EAc6xFd3b19-YNCPZqiG2NLmhKPk2nTtkCA)

---

#### Related Questions

- [How to create a generic type alias for a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720954/1366033)
- [Generic function type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58770087/1366033)
- [Function with Generic Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60178347/1366033)
- [Type of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48425137/1366033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this function:

```js
const fetchData = <T,>(): T[] => {
    const arr: T[] = []
    arr.push(2) // error
    arr.push('str') // error

    return arr
}
```

is hard to use.

Since non of your arguments are not related to `T`, TS will not allow you to `push` any value to the `arr`. Of course, you can use type assertion `as`, but it is very unsafe:

```js
const fetchData = <T,>(): T[] => {
    const arr: T[] = []
    arr.push('str' as any as T) // error

    return arr
}

const emptyStringArray = fetchData<number>(); // number[]
emptyStringArray[0].toExponential() // runtime error
```

Related [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596), [my article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints)

The answer is easy and simple: it is impossible in this case to separate `T` from function definition without workarounds.

Here you have simplest way:

```js
const fetchData = <T,>() => {
  const arr: T[] = []
  return arr
}
```

However, if you want to mutate your array inside `fetchData`,  this function signature is not useful. This function is not allowed to do anything with `arr`. All you can do is to return `arr` without any mutations.

In order to mutate this list, you need create higher order function and during calling `fetchData` provide explicit generic argument:

```js
type FetchData = <T>() => T[]
const fetchData: FetchData = () => []

const higherOrder = <T,>(elem: T) => {
  const arr = fetchData<T>();
  arr.push(elem)

  return arr
}



const test = higherOrder('str'); // ok, string[]
const test2 = higherOrder(42); // ok, number[]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7K24N)

Answer (score 2):

`IFetchData` is doing the return typing for you, so it should work to omit the generic from the `fetchData2` function return. Does the following work?

```js
type IFetchData = <T>() => T[]
const fetchData2: IFetchData = () => {
  return [];
}
```

Comment: Close, but ideally I'd be able to keep the generic in the definition.  It got simplified out in trying to create a small example, but I'm actually creating an initial array and pushing obects to it - Updated Example

Comment: Hmm, if you need access to the generic inside `fetchData2` it seems like the approach would be similar to your initial approach (without `IFetchData`: `const fetchData2 = <T>() => { const arr: T[] = []; return arr;}`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it?

```
type IFetchData = <T>() => T[]
const fetchData2: IFetchData = <T>() => {
  return [];
}
```